# Why isn't the gets keyword in ruby working in sublime text 3? What do I need to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext3

I'm new to coding and have been learning ruby and javascript recently and whenever I'm practicing ruby and use the gets keyword in sublime text 3 nothing works. I can type stuff in the console but the rest of the program won't run

Answer (score 2):

`gets` won't work if you're running the script via the Sublime 'build' command. The reason is that Sublime runs your code in a *non-interactive shell*.

You will have to run the file with a terminal, like `ruby <my_file.rb>`

You can see the same result with the following (the gets won't work in either):

```
# in ruby, gets won't work in a background thread
Thread.new { gets.chomp }

# in bash, gets won't work in a backgrounded process
$ ruby -e "gets.chomp" &
```